# Have a Queue subscribed to multiple Queues, programmaticaly

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue, messaging

I have two Virtual Topics: T1, T2. I have a consumer named FOO.

```
session.createTopic("VirtualTopic.T1");
session.createTopic("VirtualTopic.T2");
```

With this I can get messages for every one of the queues using this:

```
destination = session.createQueue("Consumer.FOO.VirtualTopic.T1");
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
Message msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();

destination = session.createQueue("Consumer.FOO.VirtualTopic.T2");
consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
Message msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();
```

**Is there a way I can "subscribe" a new Queue (let's name it "FOOqueue") to the previous queues `Consumer.FOO.VirtualTopic.T1` and `Consumer.FOO.VirtualTopic.T2`?**

This way I could create a consumer pointing only at "FOOQueue" and get all the messages (and in future I could subscribe to other queues from "FOOQueue" and get messages from other queues as well).

Comment: are you familiar with [distributed queues](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html)? Because to me, that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well I don't need to communicate to other brokers. I only need one broker, but the possibility to have a queue to subscribe to 1 or more queues, so I can fetch all the messages for a specific user using only 1 queue. Thanks for your response @eis :)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking given that queues don't subscribe to other queues, and you question contains code for consumers being subscribed to a queue.  Please clarify what you mean here.

Comment: @TimBish what I want is to consume from a Queue (let's call it Q3) that contains the messages from queues Q1 and Q2. If this is not possible with Queues, could it be possible using Topics?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for sounds like [Composite Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) as defined in the ActiveMQ broker configuration.  You would define a composite destination that consist of messages forwarded from some other queues.  This of course requires broker reconfiguration if you need to add more forwards later on.